# SQL query to get duplicate record counts based on other factors

Tags: sql, duplicates, field

I have a table (participants) which has multiple columns that could all be distinct. 
Two columns that are of special interest in this query are the userID and the programID
I have a two part inquery here.

1. I want to be able to acquire the list of all userIDs that appear more than once in this table. How do I go about doing it?
2. I want to be able to acquire the count of all programID's where the same userID appears in multiple programIDs. (I.E. count of programs where same userID appears in 2 programs, count of programs where same USErID appears in 3 programs, etc...)
    For Example:

   ```
    programID: prog1
       userID: uid1
       userID: uid3
       userID: uid12
    programID: prog2
       userID: uid3
       userID: uid5
       userID: uid14
       userID: uid27
    programID: prog3
       userID: uid3
       userID: uid7
       userID: uid14
       userID: uid30
    programID: prog4
       userID: uid1
   ```

   Expected Results:
        userID count = 2; programs = 3
        userID count = 3; programs = 3

Can anyone please help me with this.

my current code for question 1 is:

```
    SELECT 
    WPP.USERID, 
    WPI.EMAIL, 
    WPI.FIRSTNAME, 
    WPI.LASTNAME, 
    WPI.INSTITUTION 
    FROM WEBPROGRAMPARTICIPANTS WPP 
    INNER JOIN WEBPERSONALINFO WPI 
    ON WPP.USERID = WPI.USERID 
    INNER JOIN WEBPROGRAMS WP 
    ON WPP.PROGRAMCODE = WP.PROGRAMCODE 
    WHERE 
    WP.PROGRAMTYPE IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6', '9', '10') 
    GROUP BY 
    WPP.USERID, 
    WPI.EMAIL, 
    WPI.FIRSTNAME, 
    WPI.LASTNAME, 
    WPI.INSTITUTION 
    HAVING COUNT(WPP.USERID) > 1
    ORDER BY WPI.EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue on my side, with a logic step that was left out.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
select userID , SUM(userID ) AS Count 
from Preparations 
group by userID where Count > 1
```

Comment: I believe it should be COUNT(userID) AS Count.

Answer (score 0):

Your query for part one looks good. Here's your query for part 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.programID, COUNT(p1.userID) AS Multiple
FROM participants p1
JOIN participants p2 ON p2.userID = p1.userID
GROUP BY p1.userID, programID
ORDER BY Multiple, programID
```

It lists programID and the number of other programIDs that the same userID appears in for each programID. I think your expected results are wrong for your sample data. It should be:

userID count = 1; programs = 3;
userID count = 2; programs = 4;
userID count = 3; programs = 3;

You can use the above as a subquery (derived table) if you want to fine tune the results to look more like your expected results.